# How to open a URL in an SSRS report in a new window? While the URLs keep changing in every record

Tags: html, sql, url, reporting-services

I want to be able to open links in a new window in my SSRS report. The problem is these links are not the only things present in the record, and there is other data present. I keep seeing examples where they are considering only a link to be present in the record with no other data.

Also the data in the record includes HTML tags and I checked the option that says "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles" on the placeholder properties window.

Example of data in the record:

```
Hello! Welcome to google, the most used search engine. 
Click on www.google.com to go the website
```

So when I click on the www.google.com URL, it should open in a new window.

Edit: The URLs keep changing in every record.

Answer (score 0):

If you setting the action of a textbox (for example), it you set the action as `Go to URL` that in-effect giving you the ability to type anything into the address bar.

So you can use javascript....

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://" & Fields!URL.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

or some combination there-of

Comment: Sorry, I should've probably mentioned this, but the URLs keep changing in every record. Thanks.

Comment: Updated based on comment